# Datatype to store password in encrypted format in oracle 11 g

Tags: java, encryption, oracle11g, passwords

> I am creating  a user table where in I need to store the password in
>   an encrypted format.I need to know what **datatype** can be used to
>   create a column which accepts the encrypted password.Basically I don't
>   need any function to encrypt the password.This has to be taken care
>   when we create the table itself.

As per this link

> https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/storing-passwords-in-the-database-9i

Varchar is sufficient for it.Please let me know any other datatypes
that can hold the encripted password.

Database: Oracle 11g.

TIA

Pradeep

Comment: The article you linked to tells you to store a hash, so are you you just using the word 'encrypted' incorrectly? What data type does your hashing function  generate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly suggest not to store the password in any encrypted format. Rather, create some kind of hash value from the password, and store this value instead. This way the password can not be de-crypted, but you are still able to verify the password by generating the hash for the entered string and comparing it with the stored hash value. Just search for password hashing methods, you will find the best for yourself. Then the hash value can be stored in a simple VARCHAR field, nobody will be able to use it as a password.

Comment: Don't forget to salt it, to protect from frequency analysis and rainbow table look-up attacks!